# Overlay video with video - Python

Tags: python, video, overlay

I'm looking to **build a program in python allowing to overlay a video on a video** such as 1 video as background and another one on the left top corner. The goal is then to automate it.

I've find methods to overlay images on videos using overlay and watermark but not to overlay videos. Then, I've find methods using FFMPEG but the goal is to make it through Python.

Would you guys have any ideas/resources on the way to 1)overlaying video on video with Python 2) automate the process on a second time ?

Thanks!

PS: I am using Python 3.7 with Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach regarding this topic is very powerful and generalizable. Since the author of the question did not provide any example, I'll stay in the general case.

Consider a video as a series of pictures (which can be represented as `numpy` arrays. Once you read the whole series it in, you can do anything with it. Assume the background vid is called `video1` and the one in the top left corner `video2`. Since a picture basically is a matrix you can create a new video with moviepy and in each timestep do the following:

1. create new numpy array `video_combined`
2. write current step of `video1` into it
3. overwrite corresponding pixel values in top left corner with `video2` (probably sliced or compressed, use opencv for example)
4. append this to new video

Alternatively (and a little bit easier), use the concatenation methods of moviepy ([documentation link](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html#stacking-and-concatenating-clips)) for mixing videos together which seems to fully fulfill your needs.

Feel free to ask for more details to explain, if this doesn't fit your question already!

Comment: Thank you very much @Nico , I really appreciate your help and yes it fitted my question. I actually used the CompositeVideoClip method for my case and created a little program to automate the process of making a video with a video in the background, another one on the bottom right corner via the command line. I can share it I wanted :)

Comment: Hi, do you still have the code? If so, could you share it?

Comment: Hey @DavidA. , there is no code mentioned here, just an algorithm of how one would easily create that code. Feel free to apply that algorithm to any video you have at hand!